# What do we achieve by imposing ARMA structure on a stationary stochastic process?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have some set of data $\{x_t\}_{t=1}^T$, which we model as a part of realization of stationary stochastic process $\{X_t|t\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Now, as I understand, by a virtue of [The Wold Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem), we can represent this process as $MA(\infty)$- series of elements constituting White Noise. Further, we can approximate this representation by a stationary solution of some $ARMA(p,q)$ equation. I perceive this as a justification of $ARMA$ modelling, where we restrict considered family of stationary stochastic processes to its particular subset: stationary solutions of $ARMA$ equations. Here, my question arises: what we achieve by doing this in a context of prediction? What are advantages of this approach over simply considering a $\textbf{linear projection}$ of a variable of interest on its past values, which minimizes $MSE$ among all linear forecasting functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the advantages of ARMA over a linear projection, i.e. an AR model:
In many cases, ARMA(p,q) offers a more parsimonious approximation of MA($\infty$) than an AR(p') could.$^*$ Due to the bias-variance trade-off, parsimonious models tend to be better at prediction.

$^*$<sub>I used p' to distinguish from p, as the do not have to coincide.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need one clarification: am I right in saying that due to The Wold Decomposition, we obtain a structure of our process, which we can approximate (e.g. by ARMA or AR models); this in turn enable us to simplify our expressions for optimal forecast procedures like conditional expectation and linear projection?

Comment: @Mentossinho, yes, absolutely.